# Python while loop does not work properly

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am using a `while` loop inside a `if` / `else` condition. For some reason under one condition the while loop does not work. The condition is shown in my code below. Under these conditions I would assume that the `else` condition should be utilized and the `weight` and the `max_speed` should be decreased until both `while` conditions are not valid anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
weight = 0
max_speed = 15

if weight == 0 and max_speed <= 10:
    while weight == 0 and max_speed <= 10:
        weight=weight+1
        print(weight)
        print(max_speed)
else:
    while weight != 0 and max_speed > 10:
        weight = weight-1
        max_speed=max_speed-1
        print(weight)
        print(max_speed)
```

Comment: What is the use of while loop here? I can't just understand the logic behind it. What are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: It goes to the `else` branch but since weight is `0` the `weight != 0` evaluates to `False` and therefore the whole `weight != 0 and max_speed > 10` expression evaluates to `False`. And that is why the `while` loop doesn't run.

Comment: Do you want the `weight=0` and `max_speed=10` ??

Comment: It's a simplified example of my real problem (for which the code is more longer). I have two conditions, which in this example are weight and max_speed. If my weight and max speed are low values then I would like to increase the weight just a little. And if the weight and max_speed (or one of them) is a high value I would like to decrease the values until they are in my desired range.

Comment: You have 2 variables but only 2 cases/combinations covered with the `if` and `else` conditions. Whatever you want to achieve, you should use more `else`-statements or use `or` instead of `and` to cover all combination of the 2 variables weight and max_speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need your `weight=0` and `max_speed=10`; You can do this ->

```
weight = 0
max_speed = 15

while weight !=0 or max_speed > 10:
    if weight>0: 
        weight = weight-1
    else:  
        weight = weight+1
    if max_speed>10:
        max_speed=max_speed-1
    print("{} {}".format(weight, max_speed))
```

Your output looks like ->

```
1 14
0 13
1 12
0 11
1 10
0 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused between `or` and `and`.

`and` means that the expression will be `True` if both condition satisfies. Where `or` means any condition satisfies.

Now based on your code:

```
weight = 0
max_speed = 15

if weight == 0 and max_speed <= 10:
    # Goes to else block since max_speed = 15 which is >10
else:
    # This while won't be executed since weight = 0
    while weight != 0 and max_speed > 10:
```

Comment: If I use or, the code keeps running and does not end.

Comment: It is based on the logic what you want to achieve. I have updated the explanation in my answer, may be that will help.

Comment: In the first `while` loop , you should add `max_speed += 1` for change max_speed value

Comment: what is the need of two different while loop here? To me @jbsu32's answer is more appropriate

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: I was not telling him the solution, but the cause of the problem. And left the implementation to the user to implement which I believe will be more helpful to him.